# Fork System Call

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, fork

when a process calls fork and it succeeds should it stay in the running state ? what about child whether it is brought to running state? Similarly when  process calls exec and it succeeds should it stay in the running state? Similarly when  process calls wait and it succeeds should it stay in the running state?

Comment: Why would the functions return a "success" value to a program that is not running to check the value?

Comment: What do you mean by "should"? According to what goals?

Answer (score 0):

check:

```
man fork
man exec
man wait
```

Except lastest one, if fork/exec succeed, parent and child processes stay in RUNNING state.

Answer (score 0):

When you fork, the child and parent are both running, and what defines whether or not a process actually has control of the CPU is your OS context switching between the different processes.

When you call exec and it succeeds, the entire program state is cleared and whatever you tried to exec will be the only thing that process does.